# Priority issue. An idea of ​how to make connections between entities work

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Bill 
( Bill_Number int(25) NOT NULL
, Total_Price int(25) NOT NULL
, Doctor_ID int(25) NOT NULL
, Insurance_Number int(25) NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(Bill_Number)
);

CREATE TABLE Insurance 
( Insurance_Number int(25) NOT NULL
, Total_Price int (25) NOT NULL
, Patient_ID int(25) NOT NULL
, Bill_Number int(25) NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(Insurance_Number)
);
```

I'm having trouble with 2 tables: Bill and Insurance.
In my database.. there is supposed to be 1 Insurance to many bills but i can understand how to prioritize it.
HELP PLEASE...

Comment: if there should be one insurance to many bills then the Bill table should have a foreign key to Insurance, and Insurance need not contain Bill_Number, since that can only hold one value per record. And of course you have to create Bill after Insurance in the create statements. You seem to have got it the wrong way round here (in your code, there can be many insurances to one bill) - so just do the reverse of what you have now.

Comment: INT(25) isn't a thing (and is merrily ignored by the parser) - and FWIW, 'buissiness' isn't a word (and neither is botique)

Comment: I cant reverse it because I need to use the Payment table...

Comment: What difference does that make?

Comment: I can't see how your payment table is relevant to this issue either. Please explain what you think the problem is with that.

Comment: I probably had a problem with the foreign keys but I figured it out. Thank you!!!